# can use eloquent model in blade view?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, view, model, laravel-blade

for example this is our simple blade view that called dashboard and our class model is "user"
does it work to take use it inside blade like following code? line 1,12

```
{{use App\Models\User;
$user= User::where('id', '1234')->first();}}
<x-app-layout>
<x-slot name="header">
<h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
{{ __('Dashboard') }}
</h2>
</x-slot>
<div class="py-12">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
            <div class="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
                {{ $user->name }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `use` is a PHP directive (is that the correct word?) so needs to be wrapped in a `<?php use App\Models\User; ?>` block (or the equivalent `@php ... @endphp` blade block) however you don't actually make use of `User` as a class here. Only `$user` as a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing things, you SHOULD pass variables to the view IN the controller and then use them in the view (as of your line 12th)

To use that variable in the view, you should pass it in the controller: i.e:

```php
publix function index(){
   $user = User::find(1);
   return view('index',['user'=>$user]); //'user' is the name of the variable in the view and $user the value that variable will take
}
```

Then you can use `{{$user->id}}`

the "use App\Models\User;" syntax should only be used on Controllers or PHP classes, if you indeed need to use the actual model in view (in a loop for example) you can achieve that also!

```php
@foreach(App\Models\User::all() as $user)
    <!-- html code -->
@endforeach

<!-- OR -->

{{ App\Models\User::find(104)->name }}
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 2):

You can import classes in .blade.php files the same way you would in any other .php file:

```
@php
use App\Models\User;
$user= User::where('id', '1234')->first();
@endphp
<x-app-layout>
<x-slot name="header">
<h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
{{ __('Dashboard') }}
</h2>
</x-slot>
<div class="py-12">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
            <div class="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
                {{ $user->name }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this particular case there's little benefit in doing this though and it's generally not a good idea to have database queries happening in view code since views should not be responsible for retrieving models. That's the responsibility of the controller or helpers called from the controller.

Answer (score 1):

you should define all your logic in controller and model.
And pass the data in variable to the blade file.

And there you can use all data using

```
@foreach(....)

@endforeach
```